# See that the patient {has/will be having} complete rest

Tags: tense, verbs, exam-questions

> See that the patient _________ complete rest

Options given are:

> A. having
> B. will have
> C. has
> D. will be having

The given answer is **"has"**.

I think **has** is used as the main verb here. Can we use **has/have** as a main verb apart from the meaning of **possession**?

Also, why is the fourth option (**will be having**) not the answer?

Comment: The best one is "has". "Have" is generally stative. That is why may be. As for the usage of "have" other than the meaning of possession: 'he had his hair cut', 'can you have him complete the homework?'.

Comment: Man_From_India, I agree. One could use "will have", but more typical would be "will get" or "gets", when "has" is not used. But off the top of my head I cannot answer WHY "will be having" is not a proper construction.

Comment: "Will be having" does not fit "see that". "See that" means *(You) see (to it) that...* It is a command and as *see* is in the present tense, so must be what the commanded person is going to do. Plus, "will be having" is passive, which doesn't fit the imperative and active voice of the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @FeliniusRex How is "will be having" passive? It is clearly Future continuous...

Comment: @jbn: There is the idiom [to have a/some/complete rest](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rest), so this has nothing to do with the verb to "have" used to show possession.

Comment: @fev You're right. It's not passive. That part of my statement was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The construction

> See that X happens

is a command to someone to make sure X does happen. The natural follow on is *has* since we have an idiom *to have a rest* or *to have a good night's sleep*. It has nothing to do with possession. It would be possible to substitute *will have* for *has*.

A posible use case for *will be having* might be

> The patient will be having a complete rest when the ward round starts.

The continuous *will be having* is interrupted by some other event.